# Extracting a password from a sentence using NLP

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am developing a bot, which will be used for account management. I'm currently trying this with the [yake](https://github.com/LIAAD/yake) but am open to other suggestions.

I want to parse sentences similar to the one below

```
Add a mail account XYZ  with username Xname with password XYZ@123#
```

I need to extract `mail`, `Xname` and `XYZ@123#` but am unable to do this. The library doesn't parse the password since it's meaningless.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Sachin! Could you please share the code that you have tried? It would help us understand your problem in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are sentences always like `"...mail account <account_name> ... username <username> ... password <password>"`?
In this case you can use regexes. I can write the corresponding code if needed.

Otherwise, you should investigate [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) library and is Named Entity Recognition. Start by this [tutorial about training your own NER with SpaCy](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/training-a-spacy-ner-pipeline-with-prodigy-ca58350cb868).